# Apply Row Pattern From One DF Onto Another DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, google-colaboratory

Lets say i have this dataframe:

```
| letters1|Classification|
|    A    |    vowel     |
|    B    |  consonate   |  
|    C    |  consonate   |
|    D    |  consonate   |
|    E    |    vowel     |
```

And this other one:

```
| letters2|Classification|
|    L    |              |
|    K    |              |  
|    O    |              |
|    U    |              |
|    I    |              |
```

How can i automatically make python classify all letters in the 2nd dataframe based on the pattern expressend in the first?

Obs.: i'm using colab, but i've installed anaconda

Comment: What's the pattern in the first dataframe? Said differently, what is the expected output?

Comment: It is pretty obvious right? Check if a letter is a vowel or a consonante

Comment: @TCMolenaar - at that point, the first dataframe is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with all vowels and check if the letter is in the list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'letters': ['L', 'K', 'O', 'U']})

vowels = ['A', 'E', 'O', 'U', 'I']
df.loc[df.letters.isin(vowels), 'Classification'] = 'vowel'
df.loc[~df.letters.isin(vowels), 'Classification'] = 'consonate'
```